# camel-azure underlying protocol for azure blob https or http

Tags: apache-camel, azure-storage

Which protocol does the camel-azure component use internally?
Are the calls HTTPS or HTTP?
I need to decide whether or not to encrypt the blob content.
I think it uses HTTPs by default. Did not find any option to override in the Azure documentation or the blob code

Answer (score 2):

answering this on my own. BlobServiceUtil.prepareStorageBlobUri uses HTTPS